# Web.py template error: 'sum' does not exist

Tags: python, web.py

I use the built in 'sum' function in a web.py templator template and I get the following error:

```
global name 'sum' is not defined
```

Source code is below:

```
$if profs:
   $for prof in profs:
      $sum([1, 2, 3])
```

I can use 'sum' just fine at a Python REPL in the terminal.

What could be the issue?

Thanks,
Jacob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the functions in a dict and pass as the globals argument to render:

```
render = web.template.render('templates/', globals={'sum': sum})
```

Then in your template you can just use it:

```
$def with (numbers)

<h1>Numbers add to $sum(numbers)</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all python code is available in template notation, try something like this:

```
$if profs:
   $for prof in profs:
      $code:
         mysum = sum([1, 2, 3])
      $mysum
```

Comment: Nope, error persists. 

I just want to sum a list, I would figure that would be part of the Python subset they would allow in templates, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Template languages usually don't allow for direct instantiate of function calls.  You might have to do something to assign the `sum` value ahead of time, such as by way of an attribute or a method.